# How do I access a JSON key which was passed by argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I'm basically checking if certain indicators exist in a Javascript Object and if they exist, I want to return their value.
Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
public haveInIndicators(indicator: any): boolean {
    if(indicator in this.existingIndicators) {      # this condition returns true
        return this.existingIndicators.indicator;
    }
}
```

`this.existingIndicators` is a variable defined somewhere else, but a console.log on it returns:

```
currency: true
__proto__: Object
```

A console.log on the passed indicator returns `currency`. However, `this.existingIndicators.indicator` returns `undefined`.

How can I check if the passed argument does exist as a JSON key and return its value if it indeed exists?

Comment: is this. existingIndicators.indicator is an object and you try to check the existence of key right?

Comment: `indicator` is a variable, try to read it as `this.existingIndicators[indicator]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` to check for the presence of the supplied key as an *own* property and the `[]` notation to query for dynamically supplied properties.

The `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` will check for the presence of the property on the object itself and *not on the prototype chain*, whereas the `in` operator will check in the own properties as well as on the prototype chain:

```
public haveInIndicators(indicator: string): boolean {
    if(this.existingIndicators.hasOwnProperty(indicator)) {     
        return this.existingIndicators[indicator];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read a value from object using a variable, you can use `[varName]`
in this case, it will be `existingIndicators[indicator];`

```js
const existingIndicators = {
currency: true,
};

const haveInIndicators = (indicator) => {
  if(indicator in existingIndicators) {  
    return existingIndicators[indicator];
   }
};

// Or you can use an improved version of above function
// it will fallback to "undefined" if value not present!
const improvedHaveInIndicators = (indicator) => {
  return existingIndicators[indicator] || undefined;
};


const value = haveInIndicators('currency');

console.log('value ', value);

const improved = improvedHaveInIndicators('currency');

console.log('improved ', value);
```